# Как сократить полное ФИО в python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Я сделал фикцию которая сокращает полное ФИО.

ФИО - Иванов Иван Петрович
Результат  - Иванов И.П.

Функция:

```
n = ФИО
parts = n.split(' ')
name = (parts[0] + ' ' + parts[1][0] + '.' + parts[2][0] + '.')
```

К примеру в одной строке (ячейки) находится 2 (два) полных ФИО.

**Как построить функцию чтобы она сокращала (работала) с одним и с двумя ФИО?**

ФИО:

```
Жуковский Иван Петрович
Сидоров Николай Петрович, Петрова Марина Николаевна
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
Жуковский И.П.
Сидоров Н.П., Петрова М.Н.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно одним махом через замену, используя регулярное выражение.

```
import re
data = 'Сидоров Николай Петрович, Петрова Марина Николаевна'

new_data = re.sub(r'\b(\w+)\b\s+\b(\w)\w*\b\s+\b(\w)\w*\b', r'\1 \2. \3.', data)
print(new_data)
```

```
Сидоров Н. П., Петрова М. Н.
```

Answer (score 5):

Так для одного имени:

```
user_name = 'Иванов Иван Иванович'
user_name_list = user_name.split(' ')
print(f'{user_name_list[0]} {user_name_list[1][0:1]}.{user_name_list[2][0:1]}.')
```

А так для списка имен:

```
users = ['Жуковский Иван Петрович', 'Сидоров Николай Петрович', 'Петрова Марина Николаевна']
change_users = []
for name in users:
    cache = name.split(' ')
    change_users.append(f'{cache[0]} {cache[1][0:1]}.{cache[2][0:1]}.')

print(*change_users)
```

Answer (score 1):

Работайте над проблемами постепенно, декомпозируя задачу на части и решая эти части по отдельности:

- напишите функцию, которая делает ФИО из одного Имени Отчества Фамилии
- напишите функцию, которая разделяет строку на отдельные Имя Отчество Фамилию, а дальше можно использовать первую функцию

```
def fio(name):
    parts = name.split()
    return f'{parts[0]} {parts[1][0]}.{parts[2][0]}.'

def text_fio(text):
    return ', '.join(map(fio, map(str.strip, text.split(','))))

print(fio('Жуковский Иван Петрович'))
print(text_fio('Сидоров Николай Петрович, Петрова Марина Николаевна'))
```

Вывод:

```
Жуковский И.П.
Сидоров Н.П., Петрова М.Н.
```

Comment: Угу. - Как представить 4-мерное пространство? - Элементарно. Представить эн-мерное и положить эн равное 4. )

Comment: @Zombotron, советую почитать о [single-responsibility principle](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) ;)